# Cant get my test to pass after adding a drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rspec

I hate to keep bunging everyone but I am having another problem. I think I am just missing something really simple but I just cant find what it would be. I am on chapter 8 at the end of making the Sign in/up/and out of the sample app. But when I run the test I receive the following errors.

```
Failures:

  1) Aithentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
     Failure/Error: before { click_link "Sign Out" }
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find link "Sign Out"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:44:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User pages signup page after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
       expected #has_selector?("div.alert.alert-success", {:text=>"Welcome"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:53:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User pages signup page after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_title(user.name) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:52:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User pages signup page after saving the user 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out') }
       expected #has_link?("Sign out") to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:51:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.66029 seconds
50 examples, 4 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:45 # Aithentication signin with valid information followed by signout 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:53 # User pages signup page after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:52 # User pages signup page after saving the user 
rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:51 # User pages signup page after saving the user
```

Here is my User_pages_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } #this was what I added
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end

    describe "after saving the user" do
        before { click_button submit }
        let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }

        it { should have_link('Sign out') }
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-success', text: 'Welcome') }
      end
    end
  end
```

and my authentication_page_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Aithentication" do

    subject { page }

    describe "signin page" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        it { should have_content('Sign in') }
        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
    end

    describe "signin" do
        before { visit signin_path }

        describe "with invalid information" do
            before { click_button "Sign in"}

            it { should have_title('Sign in') }
            it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }

            describe "after visiting another page" do
                before { click_link "Home" }
                it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
            end
        end


    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email.upcase
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_title(user.name) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',     href: user_path(user), visible: false) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',    href: signout_path) }
      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign Out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign In') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my _header where most of the failures come from I think

```
<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li>
          <% if signed_in? %>
            <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li>
            <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                Account <b class="caret"></b>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><%= link_to "Profile", current_user %></li>
                <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li>
                  <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          <% else %>
            <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

let me know if you need anything else thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

capybara usually searches case-sensitive, and search for a field with label, name or id.

In first test case

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: "delete" %>

  describe "followed by signout" do
    before { click_link "Sign Out" }
    it { should have_link('Sign In') }
  end
```

Here you are searching for `Sign Out` and in link is having `Sign out`.

And about 3rd test case

`let(:user) { User.find_by(email: 'user@example.com') }` change this to

```
let(:user) { User.find_by_email('user@example.com') }
```

Hope this will solve your problem.